# How to test a dynamically list properly

Tags: c#, nunit, tdd

I want to test that a bunch of buttons on screen are responding properly, this amount this increase dynamically thought the project and will be used in more than a single test.

1. My first try was using `[TestCase]` attribute

   ```
    [TestCase("High action - Button")]
    [TestCase("Low action - Button")]
    [TestCase("Right action - Button")]
    [TestCase("Left action - Button")]
    public void WhenClickOnActionButtons_ActionStreamShouldIncrease (string buttonNameInScene)
   ```

But this means that every time that some buttons were added I would need to remember to come back to every test that use the buttons and manually add the new test case

2. Then I thought that have a container that control the buttons would solve my problem, I will lost the possibility to see which buttons caused the error in the test suite, but this can be fixed just by adding a simple message into the assert

   ```
    [Test]
    [Order(1)]
    public IEnumerator WhenClickOnActionButtons_ActionStreamShouldIncrease ()
    {
        foreach (var battleActionButton in battleActionButtons) // <- Buttons containers
        {
            // Arrange
            var changedWhenClicked = false;
            battleActionButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => changedWhenClicked = true);

            // Act
            var positionOfButtonInScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(battleActionButton.transform.position);
            LeftClickOnScreenPosition(positionOfButtonInScreen);
            yield return null;

            // Assert
            Assert.True(changedWhenClicked, $"{battleActionButton.name} didn't pressed correctly");
        }
    }
   ```

But now if the button container is empty the test pass, so I thought, let's create a test that runs before it to check if the container is empty

```
    [Test]
    [Order(0)]
    public void ActionButtonsGroup_IsGreaterThan0()
    {
        // Arrange
        // Act
        // Assert
        Assert.That(battleActionButtons.Count, Is.GreaterThan(0));
    }
```

But then, if empty, this fails, and the next pass, so I thought, maybe I could make the tests stop running when a test fails, but then I discovered that a test should not rely on other tests, so my question is, how should I handle this kindle of case?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a case for using a proper collection as a data source for a parametrised test. In NUnit you can use [TestCaseSource](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html) for this:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(BattleActionButtons))]
public void ButtonTest(BattleActionButton button)
{
    // Test body goes here...
}
```

where `BattleActionButtons` is a real class:

```
public sealed class BattleActionButtons : IReadOnlyCollection<BattleActionButton>
{
    private readonly List<BattleActionButton> buttons = new();

    public BattleActionButtons()
    {
        // Add buttons here...
    }

    public int Count => buttons.Count;

    public IEnumerator<BattleActionButton> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return buttons.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Perhaps `BattleActionButtons` is just a test-specific class, but perhaps it would make sense in the production code as well..(?) With TDD, it often happens that you introduce an abstraction to factor your tests in a nice way, only to discover that this abstraction is of general usefulness.

If you're concerned that `BattleActionButtons` is empty, write another test that verifies that this isn't the case:

```
[Test]
public void ButtonsAreNotEmpty()
{
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(new BattleActionButtons());
}
```

There's no need to order the tests. If `BattleActionButtons` is empty, `ButtonsAreNotEmpty` will fail. It's true that the data-driven parametrised test (here called `ButtonTest`) will pass when the collection is empty, but there's nothing wrong in that. It just becomes a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

(Unit tests are essentially predicates, and a parametrised test is a universal claim that states that for all (∀) values in the data source, the predicate holds. Thus, when the data source is empty, any test is trivially going to pass, which is exactly as it should be according to predicate logic.)

Comment: "Perhaps BattleActionButtons is just a test-specific class, but perhaps it would make sense in the production code as well" <- This is my problem with this answer, this seems like I'm doing classes just to make the test pass and not really testing the actual buttons in production, I mean, isn't a requirement that we found the actual buttons in screen to try instead of creating a similar class that contains buttons and then test? Because it seems that a test that gives an okay about a class of buttons created just for the test not secure enough imho

Comment: Also, I don't think that I get how could I use the idea of [TestCaseSource], those buttons aren't something that I could create and use on code only, I need to spawn them on screen, create a virtual mouse, position the mouse into the button position, click, wait for a frame for the listener to answer and then check the state. Sorry if I'm saying wrong things but I really don't get how could I make this process using a TestCaseSourceAttribute

Comment: @Nefisto It's not really clear where or what produces the buttons, but these comments seem to imply that you want to extract them from some page or view. That was FTR not clear from the OP, but if this is so, then how do you plan to enumerate those buttons? Do you have code that does that? If so, make that code act as the test data source. The `[TestCaseSource]` attribute can, AFAICT, work with any class or method that produces test values.

Comment: I didn't show it because I thought that this was not necessary, but the scenario is as follow, the script comes from a game dev scenario using Unity, and unity internally uses a Component pattern, which means that the difference between a Button and a player is just that a button has the Button class component and the player does not, one of those components is responsible to insert/remove the button from an accessible list of buttons, the important part is that I don't spawn the buttons into the scene, just retrieve them from this list

Comment: But to use the [TestCaseSource] I must spawn the buttons thought code right? But then it seems to me that I'm testing the spawned buttons not the buttons that exist in scene, the buttons that the user will actually press

Comment: @Nefisto I'm sorry; I can't answer these questions based on the current information.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the assertion from the second test before the `foreach` loop:

```cs
[Test]
[Order(1)]
public IEnumerator WhenClickOnActionButtons_ActionStreamShouldIncrease ()
{
    // Precondition
    Assert.That(battleActionButtons.Count, Is.GreaterThan(0));
    foreach (var battleActionButton in battleActionButtons) // <- Buttons containers
    {
        // Arrange
        var changedWhenClicked = false;
        battleActionButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => changedWhenClicked = true);

        // Act
        var positionOfButtonInScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(battleActionButton.transform.position);
        LeftClickOnScreenPosition(positionOfButtonInScreen);
        yield return null;

        // Assert
        Assert.True(changedWhenClicked, $"{battleActionButton.name} didn't pressed correctly");
    }
}
```

Comment: But than you are doing more than one assert per test AND ALSO need to do the same assert in each test, does not seems right imo

Comment: If you want an entire class of tests to fail because of this assertion, you could put it in the constructor of the test class.

Comment: By constructor, do you mean [SetUp]? If this is the case, doing asserts in setup does not seems correct either

Comment: Think of it this way - if you only have the assertion in the `foreach` loop, you validate, that all the buttons *that exist* work. If you want this test to fail if there are no buttons, you will need to put that assertion somewhere.

Alternatively you can just keep the assertion in a separate test. After all, the other tests passing isn't incorrect either - the buttons that exist *do* work.

Comment: Its make sense to say that a test that check buttons responsive in a container pass when testing no buttons. So you would let the second test stay as it is and use another test (as the last one) to check if we have buttons in a container?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best aproach.

Comment: @Nefisto There's nothing wrong with a [Guard Assertion](http://xunitpatterns.com/Guard%20Assertion.html). It's a good answer.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'm kind new to all this TDD thingy, Guard assertion are a new term to me, but this seems to create a bunch of boilerplate code that must be called in each test - in link example we should call assertNotNull("found people", foundPeople); AND
 assertEquals( "number of people", 1, foundPeople.size() ); in each test that requires a list of ppl - is this really a good approach? I mean, what about "one test one assert"?

Comment: @Nefisto Which example are you referring to? AFAICT, this is the first time we hear about `assertNotNull("found people", foundPeople)` or `assertEquals( "number of people", 1, foundPeople.size() )`...

Comment: @MarkSeemann In the link example that you sent about Guard Assertion, if you scroll down their code example have these asserts

Comment: @Nefisto Ah, that! AFAICT the Guard Assertion in that example is a refactoring from a worse test. Going from a worse state to a slightly better state doesn't mean that the new state can't be improved.

Comment: @Nefisto I rarely use Guard Assertions myself, because you can usually factor the code to avoid having to do so, but they're occasionally helpful. The answer suggested here seems to be such a case.